# Using an anchor tag to link to another part of my webpage

Tags: django

Here is my code:

```
<a href="{% url 'cars' %}">Click to go to Cars</a>
```

For some reason (I'm working in sublime) the first `%` and the `u` in the URL are purple (instead of the yellow it should be because it is in a string) and when I run my webapp and click on the button the error is:

> Page not found (404)
>
> Request URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/webapp/%7B%25%20url%20'cars'%20%25%7D`

And it is looking at all my mysite.urls URL patterns and sees my URL pattern
For `webapp/` which is working because my index page shows up.

it says the current URL is: `webapp/{% url 'cars' %}` which is not what it should be and I believe has something to do with the % and you in URL being purple instead of yellow in my text editor.

I have also used regular anchor tags, but they don't update the URL they just add onto it so when I updated it to add the `cars/` at the end, my other page did show up so it seems to be simply a syntax problem. My idea is maybe it has something to do with `%u` being a special character or something.

here is my url pattern in webapp:

```
urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^$', views.index, name ='index'),
      url(r'^cars', views.cars,name='cars'),]
```

here is my url pattern in mysite:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^webapp/',include('webapp.urls')),]
```

I added the quotes and got the same error as before.

Comment: Are you using the `verbatim` tag? You're also missing an end quote after the `%}`, but more likely, the problem is elsewhere in the template

Comment: In your code a " is missing:
from `<a href="{% url 'cars' %}>Click to go to Cars</a>`
to `<a href="{% url 'cars' %}">Click to go to Cars</a>`

Comment: Show your url config.

Comment: i added my url patterns

Comment: i've also tried to do just a regular anchor tag with the url i want to go to as the href value and all it does is append the href value from that anchor tag to what was already in the url bar. not sure why.

Comment: annndd i solved it, i found out that i can just use a normal href but instead of just putting in 127.0.0.1:8000/webapp/cars, i had to put in the http:// infront or else it doesn't count it as a valid URL and therefore appends it onto the end. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

The text's color in sublime depends on the selected language you're editing, for Django Template Language, you need a plug-in, it does not matters.

I think you're missing the last '`"`', it should be:

```
<a href="{% url 'cars' %}">Click to go to Cars</a>
```

Comment: Whilst that would explain the sublime, it doesn't explain why the rendered template still receives the `{% url` text in the url. Please also note there is a close reason available for typographical errors

Comment: I think this is not a typo in the question, I think this is an error in the OP's code. Without the close '`"`' template will take `"{% url 'cars' %}` as literal, `href` attribute will always take what you give, and translate it to an url.

Comment: You can easily test this in your own application with `<a href="{% url 'ns:name' %}>Test</a>` and you'll see the url render correctly but the href will still be incorrect. (because of the missing quote), so the op's missing quote is an issue, but it doesn't solve the problem.